# linking button to required html using django python

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am trying to build a web page, where if I am having 2 buttons I can refer to different links linked to them. I have tried multiple to pull info of clicked button of form, javascript,ahref somethings not working right.
Currently I am trying this code:
for views

```
def indiCountData(request):
if request.POST.get('US'):
            (code inside working)
            return render(request,'india.html',context)
        elif request.POST.get('India'):
            (code inside working)
            return render(request,'india.html',context)
```

for html

```
<button onClick="myOnClickFn()">US</button>
           <script>
              function myOnClickFn(){
                  document.location.href="us.html";
              }
           </script>
           <button onClick="mynClickFn()">India</button>
           <script>
              function mynClickFn(){
                  document.location.href="india.html";
              }
           </script>
```

for url
if use this

```
path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('us.html',views.indiCountData,name=''),
    path('india.html',views.indiCountData,name=''),
```

The view covi.views.indiCountData didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

if use this

```
 path('',views.home,name='home'),
        path('',views.indiCountData,name='us'),
        path('',views.indiCountData,name='india'),
```

404 error code

Please guide I am confused here your answers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since the JavaScript code changes `document.location`, both buttons are making GET requests. But the django view function checks whether `request.POST` contains "US" or "India" and doesn't visit any `if` branches, and implicitly returns None.

If `POST` is not what you want, keeping your views separate for different paths may simplify:

```py
path('',views.home,name='home'),
path('us.html',views.usPage,name=''),
path('india.html',views.indiaPage,name=''),
```

```py
def usPage(request):
   (code inside working)
   return render(request,'us.html',context)

def indiaPage(request):   
   (code inside working)
   return render(request,'india.html',context)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! that worked. I have been grinding on this for quite a time.